# Not getting API response data in props using getStaticProps in next js

Tags: next.js

I am new to nextjs. I want to prerender a page on server and want to delay rendering till API call is resolved. to achieve this i am using getStaticProps as mentioned in nextjs official docs.

here is the position of the file in my code structure:-

[image]

i am exporting my getStaticProps from index.js

here is the code snippet :-

```
    export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    
        const res = await axios.get(`http://blogexample.com/blog/posts`);
        const blogList = await res.data
    
        return {
            props: {
                blogList
            }
        }
    }
    
    const Blog = (props) => {
        
        const { blogList } = props;

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('list',blogList)
        },[blogList])
        
        return(
            ....
        );
    }

export default Blog;
```

problem is that, in browser console....my `console.log('list',blogList)` statement prints `undefined`

what i am doing wrong

Comment: How did you confirm that your request if returning the response?

Comment: Also, I did not understand the use of await of the following line

`const blogList = await res.data`

Comment: as request is being made on server rather than browser, how will i check that request is working or not. but i tried to make same api call in useEffect....i was working properly.

Comment: i have also tried this const blogList =  res.data

Comment: You can console things, they will appear in the server console, where you ran the command `npm run dev`

Comment: yeah, response of the API is printing in the console where i ran `npm run dev`

Comment: Can you show the position of this file in your directory structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217641/discussion-between-siraj-alam-and-aakash-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps` is executed during **build time**. Use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)
instead.